# How to skip 'Nan' values in pandas dataframe and how to show regression line with rsquared on each plot

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

Hello I have a dataframe and I want to loop from every column and plot it to the other. Data frame looks like that.

```
col1 col2 col3 col4 col5
1    /           2    4
2    3      /    4    7
/    0      2    7    9
1    2      3    4    5
```

I want to plot col1 to col2 then to 3, 4,...etc. After the plot I want to do linear regression and show the regression line and rsquared value on the each plot. My attempt at the code is.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import linregress
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
from matplotlib.pyplot import close

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 'Nan',1], 'col2': ['Nan',3, 0,2], 'col3': ['Nan', 'Nan', 2,3], 'col4':[ 2,4,7,4], 'col5':[4,7,9,5]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data = d)
       for i in range(len(df.columns)):
        for j in range(len(df.columns)):
           if j != i : 
               y = df[df.columns[i]].tolist()
               x = df[df.columns[j]].tolist()
               df = pd.DataFrame({i: x, j: y})
               b = df.dropna(axis = 0, how='any')
               model = sm.OLS(b[i], b[j]).fit()
               if model.rsquared >0.40:
                   b.plot.scatter(x= i, y = j)            
                   sns.regplot(x=i, y=j, data = b)
```

I chose to use OLS and seaborn, because in seaborn you easily plot regression line, but can't access the parameters(at least ive read), and with OLS you can easily show parameters. And the first problem I get, I don't know how to skip if value is not intiger. In theory when you plot col1 to col2 you would just get `x = [2,1]` and `y = [3,2]`. Would greatly appreciate your help in this problem :) Code doesn't to the fit nicely. And I want to display rsquared value on the plot. Is it a ways to plot sm.OLS linear plot on the same graph?

Comment: Could you please include the code to create the dataframe instead of the `read_excel` ? Also, could you precisely explain why the code above does not work for you ? (Exceptions...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please next time describe your issue more precisely and include the code to reproduce the dataframe :)

You should convert your data to float and eliminate the columns that contain nan:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# df = pd.read_excel('mydataframe.xlsx', index_col='col1')

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'col1': [1, 2, np.nan, 1],
                        'col2': [np.nan, 3, 0, 2],
                        'col3': [np.nan, np.nan, 2, 3],
                        'col4': [2, 4, 7, 4],
                        'col5': [4, 7, 9, 5],
                        })
df = df.astype('float')

for i in df.columns:
    if not pd.isnull(df[i]).any():
        for j in df.columns:
            if j != i and not pd.isnull(df[j]).any():
                model = sm.OLS(df[j], df[i]).fit()
                if model.rsquared > 0.40:
                    df.plot.scatter(x=i, y=j)
                    sns.regplot(x=i, y=j, data=df)
                    fig = plt.gcf()
                    fig.suptitle("column %s vs column %s: R²=%.2f" % (i, j, model.rsquared))

plt.show()
```

Yields for example:

[image: example_output]

This is very crude as it eliminates the columns containing nans. If you wish to create correlation plots between the columns that contain nans, then you should rather use [`dropna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) on each considered subset of columns. Like this:

```
for i in df.columns:
    for j in df.columns:
        if j != i:
            # only keep the rows where both columns are available
            selected_cols = df[[i, j]].dropna()
            model = sm.OLS(selected_cols[j], selected_cols[i]).fit()
            if model.rsquared > 0.40:
                selected_cols.plot.scatter(x=i, y=j)
                sns.regplot(x=i, y=j, data=selected_cols)
                fig = plt.gcf()
                fig.suptitle("column %s vs column %s: R²=%.2f" % (i, j, model.rsquared))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the future advice and this and for this! If I could ask you one last thing. Can you please check my edited code, and tell me where I did wrong, because it doesn't fit correctly :) thank you so much in advance

Comment: I am deeply sorry but I can not do that: stack overflow is not for interactive help but for somehow "static" questions and answers. The way you modified your code makes it a quite different problem: now you have object types because of string 'Nan' and you override your own `df` in the loop :) so please look at the answer, and if it works for you ... accept it :) thanks a lot for using stackoverflow